# How to know when YouTube API key is maxed out (before it errors)

Tags: python, youtube, api-key

i have a python script that queries youtube on 3 different functions, but i fail to to handle the error
that the API key reached its maximum quota.
i tried:

- try and except (with the except being recursion of the function, since the function didnt finish)
- a function to rotate api keys every # of uses (failed because certain actions take different quotation "points")

Comment: The try-except approach is generally the way to go, and then either follow up with another key or try something like incremental / exponential backoff.

Comment: Additionaly to the `try/catch` approach, consider check the returned exception; if is a `quotaExceeded` exception, handle the flow as you consider the best (*i.e: showing a user-friendly message, for example*) - see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors).